# New home foundation opening

Tags: concrete-block

We are having a new home built. Can you tell me why there’s several openings near the foundation? Is it suppose to look this way? How will the builder fix it? [image]Can water get in and mess up the foundation?

Sincerely,
Simone

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Space under foundation, why)

Comment: What space, I don't see any openings? I see a cement foundation that is surrounded by dirt. Are you asking why the siding doesn't cover the cement foundation and if that would be a place for water to come in?

Comment: If talking about the black sections, that looks more like water proofing than openings.  Quite if you kick that section with you big toe, you will find it is not open.

Comment: The pic is too dark and lacking detail. Can you please post another pic with some indication of the area of concern.

Comment: Having grabbed the picture and brightened it up, there's still no sign of "space under the foundation" - just black waterproofing down low and gray bare concrete above that.

Comment: `How will the builder fix it?` ... that question only makes sense if the builder happens to be here to answer it ... actually, all of your questions are best answered by the builder